# Can't login to Ubuntu One

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one

I uninstalled Ubuntu One about two months ago and now I re-installed it. I can still login with my account through the site ([Ubuntu One](http://one.ubuntu.com)) but the client keeps telling me "*The authentication failed*".

If I try to use the *Recover password* option it also fails with telling me that my email address is not recognized (while I can use it with zero issues through the site)

If I attempt to create a new account from the client, it also fails to load the captcha **every time**.

Something is clearly broken here but I can't figure out what it is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2040783

cd /tmp
wget http://people.canonical.com/~roman.yepishev/us/qtsslrequest.py
python qtsslrequest.py

sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates

Comment: The second line was all it took to fix this issue (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/+bug/1068902)